# Why does this program doesn't add the 'None' string to the desired key when it should?

Tags: python, dictionary, debugging, input

In my program, I have a dictionary called `the_dictionary_list` described as follows:

```
the_dictionary_list = {'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png', 'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'], 'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'], 'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'], 'Ojos': ['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'], 'Pinzas': ['Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'], 'Puas': ['Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}
```

Now, the user will be asked to decide if he wants to add a "**None**" item to an array in the dictionary or not, he will then be asked which one of the available dictionary keys will be updated the with the `None` text, then the user enters the name of the key as input, the input can be within single quotation marks or not as long as it's a valid key, if the input doesn't exist in the dictionary he will have to enter one again, until he doesn't want to update one of the available dictionary keys anymore:

```
entrada = input('All right, do you want to add a "None" item to an array in the dictionary? (y/n):')
while True:

if entrada == 'y':
    while True:
        key_entrada = input('Cool, now tell me at which key do you want me to add a "None" item? Type only a valid key name:')
        if key_entrada.startswith("'") & key_entrada.endswith("'"):
            if key_entrada in the_dictionary_list:
                the_dictionary_list[key_entrada].insert(0, 'None')
                entrada = input('Do you want to add another one? (y/n):')
                if entrada == 'n':
                    print('ta weno')
                    break
                if entrada == 'y':
                    break
                else:
                    break
            else:
                key_entrada = input('That input does not exist in the dictionary, try again, Type only a valid key name:')
                
        else:
            print('you did not put single quotation marks, let me add them to your input')
            comillas = str("'")+key_entrada+str("'")
            if comillas in the_dictionary_list:
                the_dictionary_list[comillas].insert(0, 'None')
                entrada = input('Do you want to add another one? (y/n):')
                if entrada == 'n':
                    print('ta weno')
                    break
                if entrada == 'y':
                    break
                else:
                    break                        
            else:
                key_entrada = input('That input does not exist in the dictionary, try again, Type only a valid key name:')
            
if entrada == 'n':
    print('weno')
    break

else:
    entrada = input("Invalid Input, Type 'y' or 'n' without single quotation marks: ")
```

**It should work as expected, however after testing it I got the following output**:

> All right, do you want to add a "None" item to an array in the
> dictionary? (y/n):y
>
> Cool, now tell me at which key do you want me to add a "None" item?
> Type only a valid key name:Pinzas
>
> you did not put single quotation marks, let me add them to your input
>
> That input does not exist in the dictionary, try again, Type only a
> valid key name:'Pinzas'
>
> Cool, now tell me at which key do you want me to add a "None" item?
> Type only a valid key name:'Pinzas'
>
> That input does not exist in the dictionary, try again, Type only a
> valid key name:

I was pretty sure that I coded it right, but maybe I have omitted some important steps or done some *"illegal"* stuff here, so I would like to hear you guys what do you think it's making this program not working as expected?

**The desired final output should be something like this:**

```
the_dictionary_list:
{'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png', 'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'], 'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'], 'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'], 'Ojos': ['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'], 'Pinzas': ['None', 'Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'], 'Puas': ['None', 'Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}
```

For a situation in which the user decided to update only the `Pinzas` and `Puas` keys.

Comment: `if key_entrada.startswith("'") & key_entrada.endswith("'")` I think you want to use `and` instead of `&`.

Comment: Oh, aren't those statements the same? :'( @JohnGordon

Comment: No they are not.

Comment: [ight imma head out](https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.906985872.3845/st,small,507x507-pad,600x600,f8f8f8.jpg)

Comment: @NoahVerner, can you please shrink your example to the reasonably minimal one showcasing your problem? This one is quite big to read and understand.

Comment: Actually, I already changed the ```&``` for ```and``` but still got the same situation described above. @JohnGordon

Comment: I wanted to let the user decide in which key of the dictionary he wanted to add an item called 'None' if he wanted to, I coded something for that but it didn't work, and I'm looking for answers @Victor

Comment: Strings do not include quotation marks.  Don't add them to the user's input.

Comment: The key names in the dictionary do have single quotation marks, then the input provided by the user must have those too @JohnGordon

Comment: If your dictionary is as shown, then no, they don't.  The quote marks denote the begin/end of the string, but they aren't actually part of it.

Comment: I see, you are right, I just rewrote the code @JohnGordon I will post the solution down below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to @JohnGordon, somehow he illuminated me:

```
entrada = input('All right, do you want to add a "None" item to an array in the dictionary? (y/n):')

while True:

if entrada == 'y':
    key_entrada = input('Cool, now tell me at which key do you want me to add a "None" item? Type only a valid key name:')
    while True:            
        if key_entrada in the_dictionary_list:
            the_dictionary_list[key_entrada].insert(0, 'None')
            key_entrada = input('Do you want to add another one? (y/n):')
            if key_entrada == 'n':
                entrada = 'n'
                break
            if key_entrada == 'y':
                key_entrada = input('Cool, now tell me at which key do you want me to add a "None" item? Type only a valid key name:')
            else:
                key_entrada = input("Invalid Input, Type 'y' or 'n' without single quotation marks: ")
        else:
            key_entrada = input('That input does not exist in the dictionary, try again, Type only a valid key name:')               
                               
if entrada == 'n':
    print('weno')
    break  

elif entrada != 'y' or entrada != 'n':
    entrada = input("Invalid Input, Type 'y' or 'n' without single quotation marks: ")**strong text**
```